# Swift SpriteKit Storyboard

Tags: swift

I have a little question. I'm developing a SpriteKit game and it was working fine, but I deleted the Main.storyboard and my first scene of my game was not loaded anymore. After that, I added a new one to make it the main storyboard but now when my application launches it shows me the launch screen and instead of loading the first scene of my game it shows me a black screen. Any suggestions? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new View Controller will probably not be set as the initial view controller. You can fix that by going into the storyBoard and going to the third tab and find "Is initial View Controller" and make sure that box is checked. The picture below will show you where it is.

[image: screenshot]